# Android animate Image View synchronously when ViewPager is scrolled

Tags: android, animation, android-viewpager

I have a View Pager which when scrolled should animate an Image View to the direction of Scrolling.The Image View should animate to the left or right depending on the X value of the Child position of the View pager.The Image View should animate synchronously with the scrolling of the View Pager.In the below code **eat** is the ImageView I want to animate depending on the scrolling.I tried so hard I reached nowhere...If anyone could help me,it would be a great relief...

Screenshot:

[image]

ViewPageListener.java:

```
         binding.viewpager.addOnPageChangeListener(new 
          ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float 
          positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {   

  binding.viewpager.getChildAt(position).getLocationOnScreen(view_pager_child_location);
                      binding.eat.getLocaionOnScreen(outLocation);
            ObjectAnimator objectAnimator=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(binding.eat,"x",binding.eat.getX(),binding.eat.getX()-20);
    //                objectAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    //                objectAnimator.setDuration(200);
    //                objectAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    //                    @Override
    //                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
    //                        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
    //
    //
    //                    }
    //                });
    //                objectAnimator.start();


            }
                        @Override
                        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                            }
            }

                        @Override
                        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                        Log.e("State",Integer.toString(state));
                        }
                    });
```

viewpagerlayout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ripple="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/masked_splash"   >
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/intro_logo_wdth"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/intro_logo_hght"
    android:background="@drawable/splash_logo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/msked_splsh_logo"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/intro_logo_mrgnTop"/>
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/intro_detlyt"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/intro_det_lyt_top_mrgn">
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/intro_lbl_topMrgn">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
 <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewpager"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/indicator_topmrgn"
     android:gravity="center"
     >

     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="5dp"
         android:layout_height="5dp"
         android:id="@+id/indicato1"
         android:background="@drawable/radio_check"
         />
     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="5dp"
         android:layout_height="5dp"
         android:id="@+id/indicato2"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/indicato1"
         android:background="@drawable/radio_uncheck"
         />

     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="5dp"
         android:layout_height="5dp"
         android:id="@+id/indicato3"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/indicato2"
         android:background="@drawable/radio_uncheck"
         />
 </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/intro_det_lyt_img1_wdth"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/intro_det_lyt_img1_hght"
        android:id="@+id/eat"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/intro_img_mrgnRght"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/intro_img_topmrgn"
        android:background="@drawable/eat"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/intro_img_mrgnRght" />
    <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
        android:id="@+id/ripple"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:mrl_rippleDuration="350"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:mrl_rippleColor="#ff0000"
        app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true" >
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/getstarted_lyt"
   >
        <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:text="GET STARTED"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
    </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to translate the `ImageView` base on the `ViewPager`'s scroll offset.

You can use `positionOffset` or `positionOffsetPixels` to calculate the translation. `positionOffset` is the offset that runs from 0 -> 1 if you swipe to the left, and 0 > -1 of you swipe to the right (check this yourself to be sure). `positionOffsetPixels` is the real offset in pixels.

Translate your `ImageView` inside `onPageScrolled`:

```
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    binding.eat.animate().translateX(positionOffset * -20).setDuration(0).start();
}
```

Comment: Why did you give -20

Comment: 20 is the maximum distance of the translation and `-` means move to the left. I saw you make your animation here `ObjectAnimator objectAnimator=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(binding.eat,"x",binding.eat.getX(),binding.eat.getX()-20);` so I assumed you want to translate to the left by 20. Anyway, just change it to your need

Comment: Yes, that's what I am doing

Comment: will try and notify u

Comment: positionoffset is not helping me.I want the image which is above the Viewpager to move along with it when scrolled..

Comment: If I gave eat.getX-positionoffset.Will it help

Comment: Now I may need your layout design to see how the `ViewPager` and the `ImageView` being placed

Comment: Try to put breakpoint and debug in `onPageChanged` method to see if `positionOffset` is actually changing value.

Comment: -Positionoffsetpixel is animating image synchronously with viewpager when scrolled to left.How to know if user has started scrolling to left or right

Comment: Check if the `positionOffset` is negative or positive

Comment: It returns only float values from 0 to 1 when scrolled to left although it does not log 1.It starts  from 1 to 0 to the right. it does not show 1

Comment: So it does move your `View`, just combine those params and even `currentIndex` from `onPageSelected` to get the animation you want.